# unknown variable after upgrading from mySQL 5.7 to 8

Tags: mysql

After upgrading from mySQL 5.7 to 8.0 on freebsd, I keep getting the follow error, which prevents mysql to start:

```
[ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'innodb_large_prefix=true'.
```

The thing is that setting is not on my `my.cnf` file. I understand it is deprecated on mySQL 8, but it is not on my configuration.

Is there a way to fix it?

Best,
Francis

Comment: did you follow the upgrade steps in the manual

Comment: It will be there somewhere. keep looking. [see option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html)

Comment: Nope, the thing is that on Freebsd apparently it was reading configs from many different places, but not from those mentioned on the previous replies. It was on a non-default place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Apparently there was a naughty my.cnf file under /usr/local, where the variable was. Problem fixed by commenting it.